# Android ListView : How to skip a row when scrolling listview

Tags: android, listview, scroll, selection

I have a list view that has multiple data items types.

```
Group 1
  item1
  item2
  item3
Group 2
  item1
  item2
 ...
```

So when I scroll the list view, is there a way the rows of Group can be skipped without being focused/selected? I just want to scroll the "items".

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't understand what exactely you want to achieve,  correct me if i am wrong. you want instead of Row1: Group1: item1, item2, item3 | Row2: Group2: item1, item2, item3 - you will have:
Row1: item1m item3, item3 | Row2: item1m item3, item3 ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want the views that hold the group text not clickable and not selectable.
You can do that with the following code, where the `view` refers to the specific list items.

```
view.setEnabled(false);   
view.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. When I scroll the list the group items are still selectable.

Answer (score 0):

I would have separate lists for each group. Anything you put in the adapter will scroll.

[This tutorial](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/listview-header-parallax-with-sticky-view-in-android) is a cool way to acheive this, you will just have to do a separate list for each Group.

Comment: Thanks! Let me take a look!